# Setting Array Item Property Value in Callback in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have an application that is using Polymer. In this application, I am binding an array of items to the UI. The user can click a button. When that button is clicked, a task associated with a third-party library is called. When that task is completed, it returns a status. I need to bind that status to a property of an item in my array. The third-party library allows me to use a callback function. For that reason, I'll demonstrate my challenge using JavaScript's baked in `setTimeout` function.

**my-component.html**

```
<dom-module id="view-tests">
    <template>
      <table>
        <tbody>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ items }}" as="item">              
              <tr>
                <td>[[ item.name ]]</td>
                <td><item-status status="[[ item.status ]]"></item-status></td>
              </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <button on-click="bindClick">Bind</button>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
          is: "my-component",
          properties: {
            items: {
              type: Array,
              notify: true,
              value: function() {
                return [
                  new Item({ name:'Item 1', status:'In Stock' }),
                  new Item({ name:'Item 2', status:'Sold Out' })
                ];
              }  
            },
          },

          bindClick: function() {
            var items = items; 
            setTimeout(function() {
              this.set('items.1.status', 'In Stock');
            }, 1000);             
          }          
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

As shown in the code snippet above, there is another component `item-status`.

**item-status.html**

```
<dom-module id="test-status">
    <template>
        <span class$="{{ statusClass }}">{{ status }}</span>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "item-status",
            properties: {
                status: {
                    type: String,
                    value: '',
                    observer: '_statusChanged'
                }               
            },

            _statusChanged: function(newValue, oldValue) {
                alert(newValue);
                if (newValue === 'In Stock') {
                  this.statusClass = 'green';
                } else if (newValue === 'Sold Out') {
                  this.statusClass = 'red';
                } else {
                  this.statusClass = 'black';
                }
            }
        });
  </script> 
</dom-module>
```

When a user clicks the "Bind" button, the status does not get updated in the UI. I noticed the `alert` that I added for debugging purposes appears when the view initially loads. However, the `alert` window does not appear when the "Bind" button is clicked. This implies that the observer function is not firing. My callback actually looks something like this:

```
getStatus(1, function(status) {
  this.set('items.1.status', status);
});
```

How do I set the property of an array item from a callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout has its own scope. '.bind(this)' can be used to bind the Polymer element scope to the callback function. Below bindClick function should work

```
      bindClick: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          this.set('items.1.status', 'In Stock');
        }.bind(this), 1000);
      }
```

Working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/mehovu/edit?html,output

Comment: `setTimeout` was used as an example of something that uses a call back. Is this approach supposed to work with callbacks in general? I tried the above approach with my code and unfortunately, it did not work.

Comment: I think it should. If you can create a jsbin close to your e.g. then it would be helpful to see what's happening.

Comment: The `bind` approach you provided ends up passing 1000 as a parameter into the callback function. I've updated the example with a sample that more accurately represents how my function call is setup.

Comment: I was able to make it work. I have updated the jsbin in the post. Can you please modify that jsbin and post that link for further questions?

Comment: That's awesome! It works like a charm. Thank you so much for your help and persistence. I sincerely appreciate you explaining the problem to me.